# How can I in Angular 5 pass in a value from the command line?

Tags: angular, typescript

In a Typescript Angular 5 application, I know how to use environments to vary conditions based on the --env command line argument to ng serve/e2e/etc. But for one of my environments, I need to be bale to specify on the command line a dynamic VALUE and then use that in one of my environment variables. Basically, I need to be able to do the following:

```
ng e2e --env=dev -myCustomProp=999`
```

And then in environment.dev.ts, define myCustomProp like so:

```
"myCustomProp": THE_INJECTED_VALUE_WHICH_IN_THIS_EXAMPLE_IS_999
```

The only way I can see to do it is by dynamically generating my environment.dev.ts file by the process that executes the ng e2e command.